# php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: installation, setup, setup-di-compile

[image]I am trying to install our live website into the localhost

But I have encountered this error while running command

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting function
(T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\testmastersdirect\mastersdi
rect.masters-sp.com\shop\app\code\Masters\Categorymapping\Observer\Mapping.php
on line 10
[image]

Comment: Post your app\code\Masters\Categorymapping\Observer\Mapping.php class

Comment: <?php
namespace Masters\Categorymapping\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Mapping implements ObserverInterface

{

        return;
}

Comment: XAMPP is not supported. Please use docker to setup your Magento 2.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYKpPNtKgLQ

Answer (score 1):

**You missed function.**

```
<?php 
namespace Masters\Categorymapping\Observer; 

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

class Mapping implements ObserverInterface {

    public function execute()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you replaced default code to another code..recheck the code..if you commented properly to the deault code using ctrl+/